# Firebase Dynamic links Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, deep-linking

I'm looking at the best means to do Dynamic Links. I like the look of the Firebase Dynamic Links, though I don't see any real support for Cordova/ ionic apps. Does anyone know if that is in the pipeline?

Also what is the best alternative way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic term for what you are trying to accomplish is 'deep linking'. Dynamic Links is the specific name for the Firebase implementation, which comes with attribution tracking and the ability to deep link even if the app isn't installed when the link is opened (also known as **deferred** deep linking).

Deep linking is technically possible to implement from scratch, but it's *not* simple to do (tons of edge cases), and most app developers rely on some sort of library or external platform for it. Deferred deep linking is far more challenging to build and the only realistic way to get this sort of functionality is via a service of some kind.

[This open source plugin](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin) has been a popular way to automate a lot of the setup for standard deep linking, but it hasn't seen much activity recently and I'm not sure if it is still maintained. It also doesn't support deferred deep linking in any meaningful way.

**I'd recommend taking a look at [Branch.io](https://branch.io)** (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). Branch is another free deep linking platform with attribution and deferred deep linking functionality much like Firebase Dynamic Links, [a ton of additional options](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-Branch-io-vs-Firebase-Dynamic-Links/answer/Alex-Bauer-14), *and [a Cordova/Ionic SDK](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/cordova/)*. If you're already using Firebase for other functions, even better — Branch and Firebase work together perfectly.

Comment: Great thanks, clear definitions are useful! I'll check out Branch (thanks for your honesty here too!).

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you are able to get things up and running without too much difficulty